# How can I verify Google Search Console account on Flazio website?

Tags: html, google-search-console

I'm new on StackOverflow.
I'm designing a website with Flazio and I have created an account on Google Search Console.
I'm trying to verify the property with the *HTML tag* option, which says:

> Copy the meta tag below, and paste it into your site's home page. It should go in the `<head>` section, before the first `<body>` section.

```
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="w7fglrpZ1_a-8gXkpLnneLOLJfuUeYsMyMot3k8mHyA" />
```

I've tried to paste this code inside the *Script* component (I found it in the *Utilities* category), but nothing happened. I've also tried to switch between the *HTML* and *Script* modes of the component, but nothing changed.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this tutorial

[How to improve the SEO positioning of the website - Flazio](https://www.flazio.com/guide-ottimizzazione-seo-per-sito-web)

In the "Panel Search Engine Optimization" paragraph you can find the solution.

> To start open the panel management that you find on the right and click on the wheel settings. By clicking on the “Indexing Site” you will be able to carry out the optimization basic-general of the site, and that of every single page.
> a) the title of the website: must be fully explanatory of the service that you offer
> b) description: a description full of keywords
> c) key words: word, word key, words, etc.
> d) Verify your website on Search Console by connecting to the address
> https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home.
> You can observe the following procedure:
> **Click on Add Property**
> Enter the name of your website in the DOMAIN panel.
> Copy the TXT Record that will appear. (similar to google-site-verification = N4mmlc0UyXcT7Gnb3FI2S-cDSNxs-NFTLHyzuqSg-qc).
> Paste the TXT Record in the Search Console field, present in Advanced of the Flazio Indexing panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `meta` tag (or any custom CSS/JS code) through the [**Head/Body Manager** tool](https://www.flazio.com/en/guide-script-personalizzare-html-o-css-sito-web) in the *Manage Website* menu (*i.e.* the wheel icon on the right of Flazio Editor).